# How eliminate duplicate observation based on conditional and further creating a new column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with ~127000000 observations and 5 columns.

It looks like this:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("Acacia islana", "Acacia isoneura", 
"Acacia iteaphylla", "Dianthus thunbergii", "Dianthus tlaratensis", 
"Dianthus toletanus", "Dianthus transvaalensis", "Dianthus trifasciculatus"
), class = "factor"), stress = c(0.1355, -0.4237, -0.4237, NA, 
NA, 0.1355, 0.3892, NA, -0.2328, NA, 0.26, -0.4043), location = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ATB", 
"MCS"), class = "factor"), establishment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("anthropogenic", 
"natural"), class = "factor"), maturity = c(0.553891718, 0.335892308, 
0.335892308, NA, NA, 0.553891718, 0.651435898, NA, 0.407958356, 
NA, 0.602568113, 0.342996063)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I would like to group by location and in each (170) I have some species that are both, anthropogenic and natural. When that occurs, I would like to eliminate that duplicate observation but with a condition: keep the establishment as anthropogenic but other columns (stress and maturity) keep using the natural data (because those observations have no NA's). In the end, I need to create a column called "richness" which is the sum of all anthropogenic and natural in each region adding that number in all observations.

The expected output would be something like that:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L), .Label = c("Acacia islana", "Acacia isoneura", "Acacia iteaphylla", 
"Dianthus thunbergii", "Dianthus tlaratensis", "Dianthus toletanus", 
"Dianthus transvaalensis", "Dianthus trifasciculatus"), class = "factor"), 
    stress = c(-0.4237, 0.1355, -0.4237, 0.3892, 0.1355, -0.2328, 
    0.26, -0.4043), location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ATB", "MCS"), class = "factor"), 
    establishment = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("anthropogenic", "natural"), class = "factor"), 
    maturity = c(0.335892308, 0.553891718, 0.335892308, 0.651435898, 
    0.553891718, 0.407958356, 0.602568113, 0.342996063), richness = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Looks that the dplyr can do the job, but as a beginner, I do not know how to do. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of `establishment` if there are duplicates present in the data. Keep the rows for non-NA values, finally add a new column with number of rows for each `location`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(location, species) %>%
  mutate(establishment = if(n() > 1) 'anthropogenic' else establishment) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(!is.na(stress)) %>%
  add_count(location, name = 'richness')  

#  species                  stress location establishment maturity richness
#  <fct>                     <dbl> <fct>    <chr>            <dbl>    <int>
#1 Acacia islana             0.136 MCS      anthropogenic    0.554        3
#2 Acacia isoneura          -0.424 MCS      natural          0.336        3
#3 Acacia iteaphylla        -0.424 MCS      anthropogenic    0.336        3
#4 Dianthus tlaratensis      0.136 ATB      anthropogenic    0.554        5
#5 Dianthus thunbergii       0.389 ATB      natural          0.651        5
#6 Dianthus toletanus       -0.233 ATB      anthropogenic    0.408        5
#7 Dianthus transvaalensis   0.26  ATB      natural          0.603        5
#8 Dianthus trifasciculatus -0.404 ATB      natural          0.343        5
```